# How can I validate the encrypted (hashed) password in Liferay user_ table without Liferay services?

Tags: liferay-6, password-encryption

I'm moving out of Liferray 6.1, to a custom application. I want existing users to be able to login in the new application with existing Liferay credentials. When user logs in for the first time (not yet having an account on the new system), I want to be able to check his passwords against the Liferay's `user_` table and on success create an account in the new system. There will be no Liferay running nowhere so I cannot use Liferay's services for that purpose.

The question is how can I compare the user provided password to the encrypted password stored in `user_` table?

I have tried to add the `portal-service.jar` in my new application but some errors happens like :

```
com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.Jdk14LogImpl error
SEVERE: BeanLocator is null
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you mean by "validate exiting users ... with theirs current encrypted password"?

Comment: As explained we are moving out of Liferay to a new custom application and we have more than 2K existing users from Liferay that we need to validate their exiting credentials from the liferay and link them (create the records in the new app using the already existing data we have from liferayl) to the new application, we are doing this instead of asking the user to register in the new application. So Validate the user and password we enter in the new app matches what we have in the user_ table from liferay to "make sure" this is a exiting user

Comment: You are saying you want to move the data and that's fine. What is no clear is what you mean by "validating" and what encrypted password have to do with this "validation".

Comment: Oh I think I get it. You want users to start login with your new app with existing Liferay credentials and as they do you want to check those against the Liferay's user table and on success create them an account in the new system. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, that is what i want to achieve, I looked and there are ways using Liferay API, but in our case there will be no Liferay running, only the DB from Liferay will be used. also this is for Liferay 6.1

Answer (score 2):

First you need to check how is(was) your Liferay 6.1 configured. In the `portal.properties` there are few [setting related to passwords](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html#Passwords). Check the value of `passwords.encryption.algorithm`. It is by default SHA (SHA-1) in Liferay Portal 6.1

When your users log in, you will have to encrypt the password they provide using the same algorithm that your Liferay Portal instance was using and then compare the encrypted strings.

Depending on the algorithm you may or may not need Liferay Portal's API/utils for that. Have a look at [PwdEncryptor](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/security/pwd/PwdEncryptor.java) class to see what was used to encrypt the password and follow the same approach.

Keep in mind you will not be able to decrypt the password. But you will have it unencrypted from your user's input. So once you confirm the user's credentials you can store the password in your new system using any encryption algorithm you wish.